# Linux kernel build compile errors stringop-overflow and sizeof-pointer-memaccess

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have tried building the Linux kernel and I have got some compile errors. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it? (Or, what additional information do you need?)

Build system is running recent Fedora: 4.19.6-300.fc29.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Dec 2 17:33:14 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Target system is a Radxa Rock Pi 4

> export ARCH=arm64
>
> export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-

Refer to https://forum.radxa.com/t/building-debian-image-on-gcc8-systems/128/4

Yes, Radxa have a forum, and I have cross-posted there, but I think Stack Overflow has broader experience in this area.

Compile errors follow:

> arch/arm64/kernel/vdso.c: In function ‘vdso_init’:
>   arch/arm64/kernel/vdso.c:119:6: warning: ‘memcmp’ reading 4 bytes from
>   a region of size 1 [-Wstringop-overflow=] error, forbidden
>   warning:vdso.c:119   if (memcmp(&vdso_start, "\177ELF", 4)) {
>         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:277: arch/arm64/kernel/vdso.o] Error 1

and

> fs/exec.c: In function ‘get_task_comm’: fs/exec.c:1084:32: warning:
>   argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘strncpy’ call is the same expression as the
>   source; did you mean to use the size of the destination?
>   [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess] error, forbidden warning:exec.c:1084
>   strncpy(buf, tsk->comm, sizeof(tsk->comm));

```
                            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Radxa provided the answer, which was to downgrade `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` to version 7 as found in the previous release of Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this problem is to use a compiler which matches the age of the kernel you are trying to compile.

To do this, use a prebuilt compiler, install it into /usr/local and define it as the CROSS_COMPILE variable :

```
wget https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.3-2018.05/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz
sudo tar xvf gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz  -C /usr/local/
export CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/local/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

Now you can make your kernel like so :

```
export ARCH=arm64
make
```

Otherwise, to fix your bug specifically, change the following (in arch/arm64/kernel/vdso.c) :

```
extern char vdso_start, vdso_end;
```

To this :

```
extern char vdso_start[], vdso_end[];
```

Also change all references to

```
&vdso_start
```

to the following

```
vdso_start
```

However, unfortunately this will only solve the very first of a large number of bugs.